# Subtyping in Coq

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I defined Subtype as follows

```
Record Subtype {T:Type}(P : T -> Prop) := {
subtype       :> Type;
subtype_inj   :> subtype -> T;
subtype_isinj : forall (s t:subtype), (subtype_inj s = subtype_inj t) -> s = t;
subtype_h     : forall (x : T), P x -> (exists s:subtype,x = subtype_inj s);
subtype_h0    : forall (s : subtype), P (subtype_inj s)}.
```

Can the following theorem be proven?

```
Theorem Subtypes_Exist : forall {T}(P : T -> Prop), Subtype P.
```

If not, is it provable from any well-known compatible axiom? Or Can I add this as an axiom? Would it conflict with any usual axiom?(like extensionality, functional choice, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition is practically identical to the one of MathComp; indeed, what you are missing mainly is injectivity due to proof relevance.

For that, I am afraid you will need to assume propositional irrelevance:

```
Require Import ProofIrrelevance.
Theorem Subtypes_Exist : forall {T}(P : T -> Prop), Subtype P.
Proof.
intros T P; set (subtype_inj := @proj1_sig T P).
apply (@Build_Subtype _ _ { x | P x} subtype_inj).
+ intros [s Ps] [t Pt]; simpl; intros ->.
  now rewrite (proof_irrelevance _ Ps Pt).
+ now intros x Px; exists (exist _ x Px).
+ now destruct 0.
Qed.
```

You can always restrict you predicate `P` to a type which is effectively proof-irrelevant, of course.

Comment: Is it possible with UIP?

Comment: also it would be nice to know just how "Strong" this theorem is, like if I don't want to add proof irrelevance, so I add this as an axiom instead, do I get proof irrelevence? Or maybe is it just equivalent to UIP? https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.EqdepFacts.html seems to suggest the latter. But I don't really understand it, so if you can explain it, that would be very nice.

Comment: Proof Irrelevance is stronger than UIP, for instance imagine you have proofs `p1 p2 : x > 0`, where `x` is a real, then you cannot make them equal just with UIP. Regarding your second question, I don't think so, but it should be certainly close.

Comment: `now` is a "proof terminator", imported from other tactic languages such as Isar of Ssreflect. The basic idea is that `now tac` will require the goal to be closed, after applying `tac` plus some other "easy" tactics. Note that I much prefer ssreflect's `by`, as it is usualy much faster, but I have to use `now` if bound to the stdlib. The actual definition in Coq is here: https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/trunk/theories/Init/Tactics.v#L186